# Javascript Date Plus 2 Weeks (14 days)

Tags: javascript, date

I use this to get the date:

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
alert(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
```

How can I add 2 weeks ? So instead of showing 10/13/2011, to show 10/27/2011 etc

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25wNa/

I want the one input to have +14 days and the other +21

Note: **I'd like the format to be > 10/13/2011 <.**

Comment: Please, use the ISO date format: YYYY-MM-DD http://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 121, accepted):

`12096e5` is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) which is 14 days in milliseconds.

```
var fortnightAway = new Date(Date.now() + 12096e5);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CT7Fm/).

Comment: @jQuerybeast: It doesn't for me.

Comment: Ah my mistake. I want it on my format that's why I asked the question. Can you check my fiddle and the edit? Thanks

Comment: @jQuerybeast Simply use your existing code, but replace `currentTime` with `fortnightAway`.

Comment: Where have you got the 12096e5 from? Like in case I want to add more days etc.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14`, *milliseconds in one second * seconds in a minute * minutes in an hour * hours in a day * days in 2 weeks*.

Comment: Have you noticed that if you add more than 14 days, the month doesn't change?

Comment: @jQuerybeast I doubt that, do you have a fiddle?

Comment: @jQuerybeast You are adding a month to `a` and using that when in both inputs. That's why it's the same month - it's the same variable.

Comment: @alex Is this really robust, though? Like when a day is not strictly 24 hours, like happened recently?

Comment: A day isn't strictly 24 hours, but I believe it's safe to measure them at 24 hours.

Comment: As commented below: if you want to handle DST -> function addDays(noOfDays, date) { var origTimezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset(); date = new Date(date.getTime() + (noOfDays * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))); var offsetDiff = (date.getTimezoneOffset() - origTimezoneOffset) * 60 * 1000; date = new Date(date.getTime() + offsetDiff); return date; }

Comment: What if want to increase number of days??

Answer (score 54):

```
var currentTime = new Date();
currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate()+14);
```

Comment: Can you please check my edit? Id like it in a format of DD/MM/YY. That's why I asked my question because if I add on that format it bypasses the maximum days of a month. I get a value of 34/10/2011. Thanks

Comment: Just put `currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate()+14);` before you defining separate day, month and year variables in your function. It should works.

Comment: Does this work if adding 14 days would put you in the next month?

Comment: @NathanArthur Surprisingly, it does work for any number of months/years after/ago

Answer (score 11):

have made a fidle for you http://jsfiddle.net/pramodpv/wfwuZ/

```
    Date.prototype.AddDays = function(noOfDays) {
       this.setTime(this.getTime() + (noOfDays * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
       return this;
    }

    Date.prototype.toString = function() {
       return this.getMonth() + "/" + this.getDate() + "/" +  this.getFullYear().toString().slice(2); 
    }

    $(function() {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        alert(currentTime.AddDays(14));
    });
```

Comment: Can you please check my edit? Id like it in a format of DD/MM/YY. That's why I asked my question because if I add on that format it bypasses the maximum days of a month. I get a value of 34/10/2011. Thanks

Comment: if you are using the DD/MM/YY throughout you can override the dates toString function.  i have edited my answer and fiddle as per your date format. js fiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/pramodpv/wfwuZ/2/

Comment: I liked the AddDays function, however it does not handle dst switches if you want that:  So, I made it more like this:  function addDays(noOfDays, date) {
       var origTimezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
       date = new Date(date.getTime() + (noOfDays * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    var offsetDiff = (date.getTimezoneOffset() - origTimezoneOffset) * 60 * 1000;
    date = new Date(date.getTime() + offsetDiff);
       return date;
    }

Comment: Overwriting `Date.prototype.toString()` is probably a bad idea

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate()+14);
```

Answer (score 11):

`12096e5` is **a kind of magic** number. Just 14 days in **[milliseconds in exponential notation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toexponential.asp)**.

This number is the result of **1000[ms] * 60[s] * 60[m] * 24[h] * 14[d] saved in exponential notation.**

You can check it if you type **Number('12096e5')**. You will get **1209600000 [ms]** which is exactly 2 weeks in milliseconds. The exponential notation makes it obscure.

You can write any other number in exponential notation to make the life of your fellow developers more *interesting*.

[Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) has constructor which accepts milliseconds as an argument which argument can be in exponential notation.

> var d = new Date(milliseconds);

```
var afterTwoWeeks = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
var afterTwoWeeks = new Date(+new Date + 1209600000);
```

Both are the same.

Comment: *Magic number* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

Comment: Note that exponential notation is not a real-world example in the Wikipedia reference to magic numbers nor is it an example in a protocol, since it is one number defined in exponential notation as Ognyan pointed out

Comment: @alex I agree that to a large extent this is a magic number/string. It is magic 'literal' but since the confusion comes from the type of notation I wrote that it is not a magic literal which was not correct.

Answer (score 5):

Well, JS times are in millisecond, so adding two weeks would be a case of working out what two weeks is in milliseconds, and adding that value.

```
var twoWeeks = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;
var twoWeeksTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + twoWeeks);
var formattedDate = twoWeeksTime.getDate() + '/' + (twoWeeksTime.getMonth()+1) + '/' + twoWeeksTime.getYear();
```

Of course, this method falls down if you need to add months, since they're variable in length, but it's fine for adding days and weeks.

Alternatively, you use the [DateJS library](http://www.datejs.com), which has functionality for exactly this kind of thing (plus loads more).

With DateJS, your code could look like this:

```
var twoWeeksTime = Date.today().add({ days: 14 });
var formattedDate = twoWeeks.TimetoString('dd/MM/yy');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think `var twoWeeks = 1000* 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;`

Comment: Can you please check my edit? Id like it in a format of DD/MM/YY. That's why I asked my question because if I add on that format it bypasses the maximum days of a month. I get a value of 34/10/2011. Thanks

Comment: @jQuerybeast - using the technique from your the question with the `twoWeeksTime` variable in my answer will give you a valid date. Have you tried it? But anyway, I've added a formatting line of code to my answer, plus a bit of code to demo how the DateJS makes things easier.

Comment: @jQuerybeast - fair enough; I've given you an equally good bit of code that doesn't use a plugin.

Comment: @jQuerybeast - ironically, your JSFiddle goes to an error 404. But yes, I have tested it... and you're right, I had forgotten to add the `+1` to the month, but since you already had that in the code in your question, I guess you're smart enough to have worked out where I went wrong. (I've now added the `+1` though)

Comment: @spudley +1 on the month makes no difference if it works or not. Since it wasn't compiling I couldn't check if its 1 month behind to change that. It is just not compiling. http://jsfiddle.net/FQzbz/ I am not THAT good at JavaScript and that's probably why I am asking this question in the first place?

Comment: well, I don't know what you're doing different to me, but I can paste those three lines of code into Firebug followed by `alert(formattedDate);`, and it gives me the correct date for two weeks time. Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KXMEx/

Answer (score 2):

**Add or Subtract 2 weeks from current date**

Below code example give output in **YYYY-MM-DD** format

*If condition is added in the string to concatenate 0 with Month and Day which is less than 10.*

```
var twoWeeks = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;
var twoWeeksTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + twoWeeks); /* Add or Subtract here*/

var formattedDate = (twoWeeksTime.getFullYear()) + '-' +
                    ((twoWeeksTime.getMonth()+1) < 10 ? "0"+(twoWeeksTime.getMonth()+1): (twoWeeksTime.getMonth()+1)) + '-' +
                    (twoWeeksTime.getDate() < 10 ? "0"+(twoWeeksTime.getDate()): (twoWeeksTime.getDate()));

document.body.innerHTML = formattedDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following prototype method

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
     this.setDate(this.getDate()+days);
}
```

and than its very simple to use,

```
currentTime.addDays(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are formatting a javascript date in a particular format, then I think you can have a look at this script http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format. All you would need to do after including the script is this `new Date(+new Date + 1000* 60 * 60 * 24 * 14).format('dd/mm/yyyy')` and you would get the output `"27/10/2011"`

The script is pretty small, just above 1KB minified. This is the link to a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/naryad/GufvT/