# How to add weeks to date using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date-format

Javascript definitely isn't my strongest point. I've been attempting this for a couple of hours now and seem to be getting stuck with date formatting somewhere.

I have a form where a user selected a date (dd/mm/yyyy) and then this date will be taken and 2 weeks will be added to it and then date will be copied to another form field.

My latest attempt below isn't even adding a date yet just copying the selected date in one form field to another, if I select '03/02/2012', it outputs 'Fri Mar 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)', so its outputting in American format as well as the full date. How to I get it to out put in the same format and add 2 weeks?

```
function LicenceToOccupy(acceptCompletionDate)
{
    var date1 = new Date(acceptCompletionDate);
    document.frmAccept.acceptLicence.value = date1;

}
```

Comment: I like [that ans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7751977/1509853)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can do this :

```
const numWeeks = 2;
const now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() + numWeeks * 7);
```

or as a function

```
const addWeeksToDate = (dateObj,numberOfWeeks) => {
  dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate()+ numberOfWeeks * 7);
  return dateObj;
}

const numberOfWeeks = 2 
console.log(addWeeksToDate(new Date(), 2).toISOString());
```

You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d30med19/).

According to the [documentation in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)

> The setDate() method sets the day of the Date object relative to the beginning of the currently set month.

Answer (score 12):

This might not answer the question per se, but one can find a solution with these formulas.

`6.048e+8` = 1 week in milliseconds

`Date.now()` = Now in milliseconds

`Date.now() + 6.048e+8` = 1 week from today

`Date.now() + (6.048e+8 * 2)` = 2 weeks from today

`new Date( Date.now() + (6.048e+8 * 2) )` = Date Object for 2 weeks from today

Comment: One week in milliseconds is NOT `6.04e+8` it is `6.048e+8`. Also be wary of DST if using this approach.

Answer (score 7):

You're assigning `date1` to be a Date object which *represents* the string you pass it. What you're seeing in the `acceptLicense` value is the `toString()` representation of the date object (try `alert(date1.toString())` to see this).

To output as you want, you'll have to use string concatenation and the [various `Date` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/#Methods).

```
var formattedDate = date1.getDate() + '/' + (date1.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date1.getFullYear();
```

In terms of adding 2 weeks, you should add 14 days to the current date;

```
date1.setDate(date.getDate() + 14);
```

... this will automatically handle the month increase etc.

In the end, you'll end up with;

```
var date1 = new Date(acceptCompletionDate);
date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 14);
document.frmAccept.acceptLicence.value = date1.getDate() + '/' + (date1.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date1.getFullYear();
```

**N.B** Months in JavaScript are 0-indexed (Jan = 0, Dec = 11), hence the  `+1` on the month.

**Edit**: To address your comment, you should construct `date` as follows instead, as the `Date` argument is supposed to be "A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date." ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)).

```
var segments = acceptCompletionDate.split("/");
var date1 = new Date(segments[2], segments[1], segments[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, if I select '04/01/2012' (dd/mm/yyyy) the value i get in the other field is '15/4/2012' (dd/mm/yyyy) so it seems to still be adding 14 to the month rather than the day, or more likely the formatting is still wrong somewhere.

Comment: I guess it needs formatting somehow before the 14 days are added? as the (date1.getDate() + 14) is assuming its formatted as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @JBoom: `Date` argument is supposed to be "A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date." ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)). It might be better to use the other constructor which accepts year, month, day as separate parameters (see my edited answer).

Comment: Thanks Matt, format is fine but now the adding 1 to the month is messing it up, even if it's adding one or not!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for.

```
function LicenceToOccupy(acceptCompletionDate)
{
    var date1 = new Date(acceptCompletionDate);
    date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 14);
    document.frmAccept.acceptLicence.value = date1.getDate() + '/' + (date1.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date1.getFullYear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse the specific `dd/mm/yyyy` format and increment days with 14 , you can do something like split the parts, and create the date object with y/m/d given specfically. (incrementing the days right away) Providing the separator is always `-`, the following should work:

```
function LicenceToOccupy(acceptCompletionDate)
{
    var parts = acceptCompletionDate.split("/");
    var date1 = new Date(parts[2], (parts[1] - 1), parseInt(parts[0]) + 14); //month 0 based, day: parse to int and increment 14 (2 weeks)
    document.frmAccept.acceptLicence.value = date1.toLocaleDateString(); //if the d/m/y format is the local string, otherwise some cusom formatting needs to be done

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Function to add weeks to a given date
function addWeeksToDate(date, weeksToAdd) {
    // Convert weeks to milliseconds (1 week = 7 days)
    var millisecondsInAWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var totalMillisecondsToAdd = weeksToAdd * millisecondsInAWeek;

    // Get the current timestamp of the date
    var currentTimestamp = date.getTime();

    // Calculate the new timestamp by adding milliseconds
    var newTimestamp = currentTimestamp + totalMillisecondsToAdd;

    // Set the new timestamp to the date
    date.setTime(newTimestamp);

    // Return the updated date
    return date;
}

// Example usage:
var currentDate = new Date(); // Current date
var weeksToAdd = 2; // Number of weeks to add
var newDate = addWeeksToDate(currentDate, weeksToAdd);
console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 date1.toLocaleDateString()
```

Thiswill return you date1 as a String in the client convention

To create a new date date2 with 2 weeks more (2weeks = 2*7*24*60*60 seconds):

```
 var date2 = new Date(date1 + 60*60*24*7*2);
```

Comment: That's what [`toLocaleDateString`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.6) **should** do, but it doesn't in all browsers (e.g. Chrome ignores my system settings, as do recent versions, but not the current version, of Firefox).