# Date validation logic within PrimeNg's <pcalender>

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to set a min and max date within PrimeNG's . I would like for the "FROM DATE" input to not be older than 2 weeks from today's date. And the "TO DATE" input to not be more than 1 year away from today's date.

Here are my date fields.

```
<p-calendar [showIcon]="true"  [minDate]="minDate" [readonlyInput]="true" placeholder="From Date" id="setter" ></p-calendar>

<p-calendar [showIcon]="true"   [maxDate]="maxDate" [readonlyInput]="true"placeholder="To Date" id="setter"></p-calendar>
```

This is in my logic in the .ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
    
    let today = new Date();
    let month = today.getMonth();
    let year = today.getFullYear();
    let prevMonth = (month === 0) ? 11 : month -1;
    let nextMonth = (month === 11) ? 0 : month + 4;
    this.minDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.minDate.setMonth(prevMonth);
    this.maxDate.setMonth(nextMonth);
    
  }
```

[View of primeNG calender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN7kc.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the requirements you stated, you would need one `[maxDate]` attribute on each date/time control. Have one variable that sets the max for From Date to nothing greater than two weeks from now:

```
this.fromDateMax = new Date(Date.now() + 12096e5);
```

And another variable to set the max date of To Date to one year from now:

```
this.toDateMax = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1));
```

Both of these in the `ngOnInit()` will set the appropriate limits as you stated.

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-mgggre) for reference and the two SO answers I used to get the date limits:

1. [Javascript Date Plus 2 Weeks (14 days)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751936/javascript-date-plus-2-weeks-14-days)
2. [Add year to todays date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070428/add-year-to-todays-date/33070481)

Comment: Thanks @Milo that was very useful in helping me get going.

Comment: I am trying to add on to this code, how can I do a calculation of total dates between the start and end date. Say for ex, that the total days is 20 days in between. If it is more than 25 days, I can have a popup textbox stating that it is too many days.

Comment: @yabs check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Milo, Im still rather stuck. should i create 2 new variables and then subtract them and return the absolute value of the sum ?

Comment: @yabs I suppose, since you would want to isolate to the `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 0):

Only had to make a small chane to my nhOnit(). It looks like this now and it works exactly how I needed it to.

```
ngOnInit() {

    let today = new Date();
    let month = today.getMonth();
    let year = today.getFullYear();
    let nextMonth = (month === 11) ? 0 : month + 4;
    this.minDate = new Date(Date.now() - 12096e5);
    this.maxDate = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1));
    this.maxDate.setMonth(nextMonth);

  }
```